# Can't erase folder

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, trash

> sudo rm -rf

Doesn't work: `rm: .../abc: Directory not empty` which is.

```
~/Desktop/abc $ ls -anw
total 0
drwxr-xrwx   3 501  20   96 Nov  4 20:30 .
drwx------+ 11 501  20  352 Nov 11 23:34 ..
```

> ~/Desktop $ lsof | grep .../Desktop/abc

shows nothing

I've restarted my mac, but it continues. If I throw it to trash it says cannot be emptied because files are being used... I don't know what else I can do.
I've tried to move the file to an external card (and then format) but it says the file cannot be moved...

**macOS Mojave 10.14.1**

Comment: seems your abc folder is writable shared, default is `drwxr-xr-x`, so maybe that is the direction where you should investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Zina. What permissions should I use? I've tried `chmod 755 <folder>` but the problem still persists.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -lO`? executed from the Desktop folder. have you tried it from Safe Boot?

Comment: I've tried from Safe Boot and the result is the same: "Directory not empty".
Result from `ls -lO` is `drwxr-xr-x   3 guilhe  staff  -      96 Nov  4 20:30 abc`

Comment: sorry, can't think of a reason. you are the owner, you say the folder is empty, and you can't delete because 'not empty' error. and it seems to be used even in safe boot. only thing I can think of would be remove the drive and attach it to another mac, if no one comes up with something better.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Zina, let's see if someone adds more input.